# Getting an Invalid Address error when trying to write data with smart contract in truffle express box

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a function where I insert patient's info into a mapping and it works perfectly fine on remix and in the truffle console.

```
function createPatient (uint _SecretNum, string memory _name, uint _dob, string memory _bloodType, string memory _gender, string memory _city,
    string memory allergies,
        bool organDonor,
        string memory emergencyContact) public isWhitelisted(msg.sender)  {

//passing the patient info struct into the new patient mapping
        newPatient[_SecretNum] = patientInfo(_SecretNum, _name, _dob, _bloodType, _gender, _city, allergies,
         organDonor,
        emergencyContact, true);
//calling the event
        emit patientCreate(_SecretNum, _name, _dob, _bloodType, _gender, _city, allergies,
         organDonor,
         emergencyContact, true);
    }
```

There is a verification that the user is whitelisted and also I am sure the user is whitelisted anyway this is the code where I input the fields into the function

```
NewPatient: function(id,Pname,Pdob,bloodRes,GenderRes,SelectedCityValue,allergies,donor,Econtact){

    var self = this;
    var data;
    pdata.setProvider(self.web3.currentProvider);

    pdata.deployed().then(function(instance){
      data= instance;
      return data.createPatient(id,Pname,Pdob,bloodRes,GenderRes,SelectedCityValue,allergies,donor,Econtact)
    }).then(function(result){
      console.log('sucess');
    }).catch(function(e){
      console.log(e);

    })

  }
```

And this is the error I get

```
Error: invalid address
    at inputAddressFormatter (C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\ExpressBox\node_modules\truffle-contract\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\formatters.js:271:11)
    at inputTransactionFormatter (C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\ExpressBox\node_modules\truffle-contract\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\formatters.js:97:20)
    at C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\ExpressBox\node_modules\truffle-contract\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\method.js:89:28
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)     
    at Method.formatInput (C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\ExpressBox\node_modules\truffle-contract\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\method.js:88:32)    
on.js:136:15)    at SolidityFunction.execute (C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\ExpressBox\node_modules\truffle-contract\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\function.js:219:37)    at C:\Users\Youssef\Desktop\ExpressBox\node_modules\truffle-contract\contract.js:188:16


----------
```

So I anyone can see something I can't I would appreciate is so much

Comment: return data.createPatient(id,Pname,Pdob,bloodRes,GenderRes,SelectedCityValue,allergies,donor,Econtact).send({from: '0x73394368bcb4fb525482ee20cff1f2c4dec04cef'}); 

I added the .send function and now it is saying createPatient().send() is not a function

Answer (score 0):

So basically what was needed to do is

```
data.createPatient(123,Pname,Pdob,bloodRes,GenderRes,SelectedCityValue,allergies,donor,Econtact,{from: web3.eth.defaultAccount, gas:3000000});
```

this version did not recognize .send so as an extra parameter in the function you can add the from: account number